# SQL Query in Django yielding different result

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, count

I'm running a query in my PostgreSQL db and in Django using django.db.connection. But for some reason, my query in Django yields completely different results. Here are my queries and their corresponding results.

**Query in PostgreSQL**

```
WITH calendar AS
    ( SELECT d
    FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 day'), CURRENT_DATE, '1 day'::interval) d)
    SELECT n.device_name AS dev_name,
        c.d::date AS dev_date,
        COUNT(mc.id)
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT device_name
    FROM machine_counter) n
    CROSS JOIN calendar c
    LEFT JOIN machine_counter mc ON mc.device_datetime >= c.d + INTERVAL '7 hour'
    AND mc.device_datetime < c.d + INTERVAL '1 day 7 hour'
    AND n.device_name = mc.device_name
    GROUP BY n.device_name,
            c.d
    ORDER BY c.d,
            n.device_name;
```

**views.py**

```
def getMachineCount(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(
    '''
    WITH calendar AS
    ( SELECT d
    FROM generate_series(date_trunc('day', CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '6 day'), CURRENT_DATE, '1 day'::interval) d)
    SELECT n.device_name AS dev_name,
        c.d::date AS dev_date,
        COUNT(mc.id)
    FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT device_name
    FROM machine_counter) n
    CROSS JOIN calendar c
    LEFT JOIN machine_counter mc ON mc.device_datetime >= c.d + INTERVAL '7 hour'
    AND mc.device_datetime < c.d + INTERVAL '1 day 7 hour'
    AND n.device_name = mc.device_name
    GROUP BY n.device_name,
            c.d
    ORDER BY c.d,
            n.device_name;
    '''
    )
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    col_list = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

    print(records)

    result = bindQueryColumnDescription(records, col_list)

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result, default=dateConverter))
```

Comment: Log the queries at the database server to see if you are truly running the same two queries. Looks like you may not be connected to the same instance. I'd simplify/rule out a few things with comparing `select CURRENT_DATE;` from console and Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two database clients are using different timezones, the datetime literals (e.g. “2019-02-26 07:00:00”) will be specifying different values in each client.

You can change the literal to include an explicit timezone, e.g. “2019-02-26 07:00:00 UTC”, which will avoid using the timezone of the client.

Do that in any client and each will always use the same value for that literal.

Comment: That's it when I include an explicit timezone in my individual query the count matches. But how would I fix that in Django's side? I have changed the `TIME_ZONE` in my settings.py to my local timezone.

Comment: “But how would I fix that in Django's side?” — In any client, you can avoid its timezone by always specifying the time zone in any datetime literal you use for querying.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to make it work using `AT TIME ZONE 'EST'`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, it's difficult to be sure about the discrepancy.

One possibility: You have a complex join condition, some of which seems more suited for a restriction (a WHERE condition) instead.

I suggest you change:

```sql
-- …
    LEFT JOIN machine_counter AS mc
         ON mc.device_datetime >= c.d + INTERVAL '7 hour'
             AND mc.device_datetime < c.d + INTERVAL '1 day 7 hour'
             AND n.device_name = mc.device_name
-- …
```

instead to:

```sql
-- …
    LEFT JOIN machine_counter AS mc
         ON n.device_name = mc.device_name
-- …
WHERE
    mc.device_datetime >= c.d + INTERVAL '7 hour'
    AND mc.device_datetime < c.d + INTERVAL '1 day 7 hour'
-- …
```

Comment: It's really weird though. Even if I explicitly try to query one day's count it still a different result.
`SELECT COUNT(id)
    FROM machine_counter
    WHERE 
        device_datetime >= '2019-02-26 07:00:00'
    AND
        device_datetime < '2019-02-27 07:00:00'
    AND
        device_name = 'line1'`
This query yields 9248 through Django and 9153 in PostgreSQL